# Retrieve Outlook Calendar Working Hours

Tags: exchangewebservices, managed-ews

I'm using Exchanged Web Services and would like to retrieve a users "Work Hours".  Work hours is a setting on the Calendar and helps with free/busy calculations, but I'd like to get or calculate the actual values.

I have full access to the calendar.  If I can use the EWS Managed API that would be my preference.  I've searched online, and looked at the `GetUserAvailability` operation, but I haven't been able to find a method that will give me this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Exchange 2010 or later you can get the working hours configuration (documented in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202895(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202895%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) ) from the IPM.Configuration.WorkHours UserConfiguration FAI object (Folder Associated Items) using the GetUserConfiguration operation in EWS [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd899439(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd899439%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) .  eg

```
UserConfiguration usrConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "WorkHours", WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, UserConfigurationProperties.All);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(new MemoryStream(usrConfig.XmlData));
XmlNodeList nlList =  xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("WorkHoursVersion1");
Console.WriteLine(nlList.Item(0).InnerXml);
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would update this for VBA, I know it is an old thread but may help people and save them some time. I wrote the following for use in Excel to get to Outlook Calendar settings. I would welcome any feedback and tips on better/neater code writing.

```
Function GetUserWorkingHours(WHType As String, oCalendarFolder As Object) As String
' Returns user's Calendar Start or End work times
' Uses existing Outlook calendar folder object
' The workinghours data is stored in a hidden Outlook storage binary stream in xml format (no, seriously, it is!)
' ... with a sign on the door saying "beware of the leopard"
'
' Cheshire Catalyst software July 2020
'
Dim olStorage   As Object
Dim olPropacc   As Object
Dim olBytes()   As Byte
Dim a           As Variant
Dim xmlString   As String       ' xml stream text stored here
Dim objDOM      As Object       ' xml object to parse the xml stream
Dim Result      As String       ' Holding place for return value

    ' Loads the hidden Outlook xml store to retrieve WorkingHours
    Set olStorage = oCalendarFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.workhours", 2)
    Set olPropacc = olStorage.PropertyAccessor
    olBytes = olPropacc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C080102")

    ' Translate binary stream into text byte by byte (there may be a better way to do this but this way works)
    For Each a In olBytes
        xmlString = xmlString & Chr(a)
    Next a

    ' Generate the xml object to parse
    Set objDOM = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")

    ' Load the xml stream into the xml parser
    objDOM.LoadXML xmlString

    ' Filter on what we are looking for
    Select Case WHType
        Case "Start"
            Result = objDOM.SelectSingleNode("Root/WorkHoursVersion1/TimeSlot/Start").Text
        Case "End"
            Result = objDOM.SelectSingleNode("Root/WorkHoursVersion1/TimeSlot/End").Text
        Case Else
            ' Perhaps we should have tested for this before all that messing about with Outlook stores
            Result = "Invalid"     ' Invalid request
    End Select

    GetUserWorkingHours = Result

    ' Tidy up all those objects
    Set olStorage = Nothing
    Set olPropacc = Nothing
    Set objDOM = Nothing
    Erase olBytes
End Function

Sub testit()
Dim oOutlook    As Object   ' Outlook instance
Dim oNS         As Object   ' Outlook namespace
Dim oCalendar   As Object   ' Calendar folder of Outlook instance
    Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oCalendar = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)

    MsgBox ("Start: " & GetUserWorkingHours("Start", oCalendar) & " End: " & GetUserWorkingHours("End", oCalendar))
End Sub
```