# How to get working hours from Outlook for other users in the same organization

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, pywin32

I have been using pywin32 to get the freebusy information of different users in the same organization as me:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
recipient = outlook_mapi.CreateRecipient("user@myorg.com")
date = # datetime goes here
freebusy = recipient.FreeBusy(date, 15)
```

which gives me freebusy in 15 minute intervals. The values returned by the freebusy are dictated as in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbusystatus, but it does not take into account the working hours that each user sets for themselves. It simply shows them as available. On the other hand, in Outlook, I have noticed that in the scheduling agent, it is possible to see the working hours of each user as a greyed out color in the scheduler. Is there anyway to get this information from each user in the organization through python?

I have looked through other sources such as:

[Retrieve Outlook Calendar Working Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833609/retrieve-outlook-calendar-working-hours)

[GetUserAvailabilityResults shows result outside working hours in Exchange web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964520/getuseravailabilityresults-shows-result-outside-working-hours-in-exchange-web-se/28980853#28980853)

but, I can't seem to find a way to get the working hour information of different users in the same organization as me through pywin32. Specifically, I would like to get the working hours of users other than myself in a similar way to how I can get the freebusy configuration of other users in my organization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way to get these settings using the Outlook object model.  The [Retrieve Outlook Calendar Working Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833609/retrieve-outlook-calendar-working-hours) thread describes all possible routes for that.

Comment: Is there a way for me to get these settings from other users. i.e. If I am johndoe@email.com, is there a way for me to get the working hours configurations of  johnsmith@email.com?

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.